# Texture Difference EEVEE/Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I am working on this sofa that I downloaded and I am not sure why but while the texture is rendering perfectly in Eevee, it ends up looking weird in Cycles.

Would anyone know why this is the case?

Eevee:

[image]

[image]

Cycles:

[image]

[image]

This is the current texture node

[image]

Any help is much appreciated :))

Comment: Hello, try to recalculate the normals, or maybe it's a normal map problem? Ifit's copyright free, please share the file

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer! You can find the file here maybe it's easier: https://we.tl/t-AA9NIuqFW7

Comment: That Blend file doesn't include any of the texture files so it's difficult to see what's going on. Also several of the nodes in the Shader editor are displayed as 'Undefined' and shown in red both in Blender version 3.65 and 4.0.2. (The normals are correct.)

Comment: it looks like a bug of the material, what does it give if you recreate the material from scratch? (remove the current one, create a new one and so on)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: The screenshot shows that even in your Blender at least one node shows red and says "Undefined". For which Blender version was this model created? If we would know what the "Undefined" were supposed to do in the compatible version it might be easy to replace them with current nodes